# JPA - Removing of elements of a bidirectional Relationship

Tags: orm, jpa, relationship, jpa-2.0, bidirectional

Why can i remove elements of a bidirectional relation although only one side of the relation is managed in persistence context (Example I)? When i have an unidirectional Relationship that doesn't work (see Example II). Why?

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
Class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Process> processes;

    @OneToOne // Unidirectional
    private C c;
    ...

    @PreRemove
    private void preRemove() {
        for (Process p : processes) {
            p.internalSetUser(null);
        }
    }
   ...
}

@Entity
Class Process {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    ...

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        if (this.user != null) {
            user.internalRemoveProcess(this);
        }
    }
   ...
}

@Entity
Class C {

 }
```

**Example I:**

```
// Create User u1 with Processes p1, p2

tx.start();
// Only u1 is manged in persistence context and no process
userFacade.delete(u1); // There following is called: >> em.remove(em.merge(u1)); // Works
tx.commit();
```

**Example II:**

```
// Create User u and Object C c, establish their relation.

tx.start();
cFacade.remove(c); //>>MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException,foreign key constraint fails
ty.commit();
```

In the first example i use these internal methods to set in each case the other side of the relation but this other side is not managed in persistence context i think?! When i change a process of a user and save the user, the process is not updated unless i uses cascade.MERGE or if both are loaded in a transaction and therefor are managed in pc. So why does the removing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Example II, I guess you would have to call `user.setC(null)` before deleting the `c`.

In Example I, here is my understanding. You are first merging `u1` so a `u1'` gets loaded into the PC and the state of `u1` is copied to `u1'` (and that's all since you're not cascading `MERGE`), which is then returned. Then you call remove (on `u1'`), the `preRemove` gets called and changes `p1'` and `p2'`. They are thus dirty and will get updated appropriately on flush (setting the FK to `NULL`), while `u1'` will be deleted. And everything works.

Just in case, here are the semantics of the merge operation from the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 3.2.7.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
>   propagation of state from detached
>   entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the entity manager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If `X` is a detached entity, the state of `X` is copied onto a
>     pre-existing managed entity instance
>     `X'` of the same identity or a new
>     managed copy `X'` of `X` is created.
> - If `X` is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance `X'` is
>     created and the state of `X` is copied
>     into the new managed entity instance
>     `X'`.
> - If `X` is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If `X` is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>     however, the merge operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from `X` if these
>     relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation.
> - For all entities `Y` referenced by relationships from `X` having the
>     cascade element value `cascade=MERGE`
>     or `cascade=ALL`, `Y` is merged
>     recursively as `Y'`. For all such `Y`
>     referenced by `X`, `X'` is set to
>     reference `Y'`. (Note that if `X` is
>     managed then `X` is the same object as
>     `X'`.)
> - If `X` is an entity merged to `X'`, with a reference to another entity
>     `Y`, where `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL` is not specified, then
>     navigation of the same association
>     from `X'` yields a reference to a
>     managed object `Y'` with the same
>     persistent identity as `Y`.
>
> The persistence provider must not
>   merge fields marked LAZY that have not
>   been fetched: it must ignore such
>   fields when merging.
>
> Any `Version` columns used by the
>   entity must be checked by the
>   persistence runtime implementation
>   during the merge operation and/or at
>   flush or commit time. In the absence
>   of `Version` columns there is no
>   additional version checking done by
>   the persistence provider runtime
>   during the merge operation.

#### Reference

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - 3.2.7.1 Merging Detached Entity State

Comment: Thanks Pascal! I think in both cases you're right.For Example I its the last point of the above spec.

Comment: If i use for the Example I not merge but the following:

**"User u1Managed = em.find(u1.getId()); em.remove(u1Managed);"** 

Then it also works.That means the find operation yields also to a managed p1' and p2'?

Comment: @Michael The `processes` are lazy but I think `p1` and `p2` gets loaded in your `PreRemove` (and become thus indeed managed).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior:

> As the relationship is bi-directional so as the application updates
>   one side of the relationship, the other side should also get updated,
>   and be in synch. In JPA, as in Java in general **it is the
>   responsibility of the application, or the object model to maintain
>   relationships.** If your application adds to one side of a
>   relationship, then it must add to the other side.
>
> This can be resolved through add or set methods in the object model
>   that handle both sides of the relationships, so the application code
>   does not need to worry about it. There are two ways to go about this,
>   you can either only add the relationship maintenance code to one side
>   of the relationship, and only use the setter from one side (such as
>   making the other side protected), or add it to both sides and ensure
>   you avoid a infinite loop.

For example:

```
public class Employee {
    private List phones;
    ...
    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phones.add(phone);
        if (phone.getOwner() != this) {
            phone.setOwner(this);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Source: [OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters)