# Deleting a child Object leads to a JDBC Batch Update Exception

Tags: playframework

When I try to delete a "Course" object, I get this exception:
    `Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKCE6C075833B16F41: PUBLIC.TEACHER_COURSE FOREIGN KEY(COURSES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.COURSE(ID)" SQL statement: delete from Course where id=?`

The "Course" class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Course extends Model {
  @ManyToOne
  public Teacher teacher;
  ...
}
```

The "Teacher" class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher extends Model {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Course> courses;
  ...
}
```

Whenever I try to delete a "Course" from my controller (using the delete() method), I get the exception above. How do I fix it? I've tried various ways of mapping. Do I need to fix the schema of the database somewhere?

Thanks for all the help! This is my first post here, if there's anything I need to make clearer, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're trying to delete a `Course` record, but there is still a `Teacher` record that has a reference to the course you're trying to delete (stored in the `TEACHER_COURSE` join table). This is *normal*, because you have defined a bi-directional relationship: a `Course` knows its `Teacher`, and a `Teacher` knows the `Course` objects that belong to it.

One option would be to simply get rid of the bi-directional relationship if possible (eg. remove the relationship from `Teacher` to `Course` by remove the `courses` list). Another would be to remove the `Course` instance you want to delete from the `courses` list first, and then delete it (*note*: you may have to persist/merge the `courses` list first before deleting the course so there is no link anymore).

[This question on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470841/jpa-removing-of-elements-of-a-bidirectional-relationship) may provide some additional insight.

Comment: I tried to remove the Course instance from the list, but that proved to be complicated and I realized I didn't need it, so I removed the relationship. But I need to read up on those JPA docs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mapping the relationship in the inverse direction. You are mapping like course is the Parent side of the relationship, instead of Teacher. From [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1591):

> To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false. This solution is not optimized and will produce some additional UPDATE statements.

```
@Entity
public class Course extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
    public Teacher teacher;
    ...
}
```

And Teacher:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher extends Model {
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
  public List<Course> courses;
  ...
}
```